# Opinion: Multiple puppet master environments

Tags: puppet

I hope you guys will permit me an opinion question here as well. If not, please let me know and I'll delete the post.

Due to policy I need to have two separate puppet masters, one for dev and one for pre-prod, prod etc.

The best practice route is to use r10k to manage these environments, but I am dubious to put something into production that I can not comfortably support - so that will the goal I work towards, but I do need an interim solution.

What would the drawbacks and concerns be by implementing the following:

puppetmaster1 - local git repo, contains all the manifests and hieradata for all environments.

puppetmaster_prod - Client of puppetmaster1, the manifest and hieradata directories is served, enforced and managed by puppetmaster1 using the file resource to manage the manifests and hieradata directories. This will manage all non-dev servers.

puppetmaster_dev - Similar to _prod, this will receive a recursive directory from puppetmaster1 enforcing modules, manifests etc

All actual servers then connect to the appropriate puppetmaster[prod|dev]

This provides me with source control as well as a single backup point and central configuration point.
It also satisfies the requirement of complete separation of dev and prod variables such as tokens and passwords. Each 'slave' puppetmaster will only contain the manifests and variables it manages, enforced by puppetmaster1.

This will be a stop-gap only until I am comfortable with r10k, its installation and usage.

Comment: r10k is a lot less scary than you think. It's basically just running git commands, and you provide it a yaml file of what repos you want to clone and what ref you want to clone them at :)

Comment: I'll try... I don't know git that well either, but did run through the course on codecadamy.